# Hyperledger fabric, adding a new peer to existing channel, can the new peer view the old transactions happened on the channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

In hyperleder Fabric network with Two orgs ORG1, ORG2

In Org1- Peer1,
In Org2- Peer1

Using these peers new channel has been created, smart contract deployed then some transactions are already done on the channel.

After Some time, I'm adding the new org. Then adding one new peer to the old channel.
Org3- Peer1, is added to the channel. In this scenario I have some questions.

1) Will the new peer can view the old transactions happened on the channel.

2) If he is able to view the old transactions, how can we restrict it

Answer (score 1):

If new org is on the same channel obviously it will sync up with the other nodes. You can restrict it by encryption which is available in fabric 1.1. If the new org peer doesnot have the key, it wont be able to read the data.

Comment: Technically, what would be the steps, given that the anchor peer of Org3 should be informed in the configtx.yaml file?